# Application logs are not in Jboss EAP console

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, jboss6.x, jboss-developer-studio

I have application on Jboss. i have proper log on file same thing i like to show eclipse console but it's not working in case of jboss. Please let me know what is the probable issue. If you need any information from system/ server configuration please let me know so i can share with you.

Answer (score 0):

First, please make sure that you are using a more recent version of EAP 6.4.z. Secondly, for a log to be view-able in the management console of EAP 6.4.z, the log should be located under `${jboss.server.log.dir}` folder.

Comment: you mean to say my log file which i created by log4j it should be inside ${jboss.server.log.dir} folder?

Comment: @Janny Correct if you want the console to display the logs. Are you able to see the EAP 6.4.z server log?

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, if you want to see contents of the Eclipse Error Log view in a console itself, you can use ./eclipse -consolelog -debug | tee /tmp/somefile.txt

Handy for collecting error logs to attach to bugzilla or JIRA reports.